# Making Android Games

Tags: android, button, menu, canvas

Ok, so I've made one app but know I'm getting all ambitious and want to make a game.

So first I want to start off with a menu.  I would rather draw this all myself instead of using the built in classes.  So should I then override the button class to change the look or should I use OpenGL or Canvas?  Any help?

Comment: `I would rather draw this all myself instead of using the built in classes` That statement alone should be a hint that you're not ready for doing that.

Comment: It was worded poorly.  I just want the look and feel to match the game.  I'm just wondering if it would be better to use canvas or other techniques or just override the button class.

Comment: If they behave the same, then why not just override?

Comment: That's what I was thinking, just wanted to confirm.

Comment: Agreed, it's almost always best to take advantage of native libraries first, if you can. Otherwise you'll end up with something much more confusing and chaotic that no one wants to work on, including you.

Answer (score 1):

Before you go too crazy writing your own UI toolkit, have a look at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

Android already has a lot of ways built into the framework to skin your app differently than the default UI.